How can i change path before use karate.process when mock a service?
I'm a new for karate, and i tried to use karate.proceed to "transition" the api to new Url. But i see the path can not overwrite in mock.feature.
Any suggestions?
for example:
MyTest.feature
    Scenario: test mock

    * url 'http://localhost:' + port + '/v1/hello/metoto'
    * param name = 'lily'
    * param age = 11
    * method get

Mock.feature
    Scenario: pathMatches('/{version}/{say}/{name}')

    * def requestHeaders = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer 123'}
    * def requestParams = {}
    * def newurl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    * karate.proceed(newurl)

then i found when karate.proceed run, it call the url as :
1 \> GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/v1/hello/metoto
1 \> Authorization: Bearer 123
1 \> Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
1 \> Connection: Keep-Alive
1 \> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/21.0.2)
1 \> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

but all i want is to ignore the old path :/v1/hello/metoto

Have you tried:
* def requestPath = '/'


yes, the log says  “no step-definition method match found for: def requestPath ='/'。 ” I also try the same things on * def requestUri ='/'. or * def pathParams ={}, and just the same error.

@MetotoHan that shouldn't happen. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue
